# Creating a more reusable UITableView subclass with default behaviour

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, model-view-controller

Many of my tableViews need a method wich loads in more data when the last cell is displayed on the screen. To avoid implementing the same method 100s of times, I decided to make my own base subclass of UITableView, which will, upon displaying the last cell, call tableView delegate (the view controller) for a method, asking it to load more data, and if data loading was successful, will reload a table view. I though this is quite reasonable, especially when nearly every table view in my app needs this feature.

Unfortunately, `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` is a UITableViewDelegate method. And I am pretty sure, that making a UITableView subclass be a UITableViewDelegate is wrong. So, that would be I need to make a base UITableViewController class. But if implement a base UITableViewController, I will probably want to override `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` in the subclass.

Also, some of my tableViews are embedded in a ViewController, not TableViewController (as there is other stuff going, other than the table View), so that would mean I need a separate UITableViewController and UIViewController subclasses. So for this is just making things more complicated.

So how do I make this "load more data upon displaying the last cell" feature reusable (following MVC guidelines)?

EDIT: So I think I have figured out how to start. I want to have a base TableViewDelegateClass, e.g. BaseTableViewDelegate. Then, I want to subclass it, override the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`, but call `super.tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath`. Now, I still have an issue. I want to make it reload data. But I feel like having a reference to tableView in tableView delegate is a bad idea (could be a reference loop). Is there a nice solution with protocols?

EDIT3: I am also thinking of another approach:

```
protocol MyTableViewDelegate: UITableViewDelegate {

    func default_tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    func loadMoreData()
}

extension MyTableViewDelegate {

    func default_tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        if(indexPath.section == tableView.numberOfSections - 1 && indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section) - 1 )
        {
            self.loadMoreData()
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        self.default_tableView(tableView, willDisplay: cell, forRowAt: indexPath)
        //do something else here that is not done in default_tableView
    }

}

class MyView: UIView, MyTableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        self.default_tableView(tableView, willDisplay: cell, forRowAt: indexPath)
    }

    func loadMoreData()
    {
        loadMoreDataFromServer(){
            tableView.reloadData()
        }   
    }
}
```

But this looks a bit ugly.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an extension for `UITableViewDelegate` and write a default implementation for `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` in it. Then each instance of your subclass will call this implementation.

```
extension UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // do what you need here, each ViewController that conforms to UITableViewDelegate will execute this implementation unless told otherwise
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Another option is creating a base `ViewController` for all the `ViewControllers` that need that behaviour. In this case you don't need to subclass `UITableView`.

You create a class like this:

```
class BaseViewControllerForReloadingTables: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {
    private var needToLoadMoreData: Bool = false
    @IBOutlet var reloadingTableView: UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if needToLoadMoreData {
            loadMoreData()
        }
    }


    private func loadMoreData() {
        //load data
        //if loading was successful 
        if reloadingTableView != nil {
            reloadingTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Then each `ViewController` that needs to load more data to the table just inherits from this class. For example:

```
class ReloadingTableViewController1: BaseViewControllerForReloadingTables {

}
```

and:

```
class ReloadingTableViewController2: BaseViewControllerForReloadingTables {

}
```

In these subclasses you have the `UITableView` which is `reloadingTableView`. When its delegate function is called, the implementation in the superclass is executed. This way the data loading and table reloading are handled in one place, but in appropriate ways for each of your `ViewControllers`.

Of course, you can add more common functions to the `BaseViewControllerForReloadingTables` class - depends on how much similar behaviour your screens have.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I guess it would probably be better to inherit the protocol, right? So I can have a choice of using either a default one or a custom one. But how can I call table view reload from a protocol?

Comment: And can I call my default implementation if I am overriding it?

Comment: I've edited the answer, look there. Also, you're not _inheriting_ a protocol, you're **_extending_** it and giving one of its functions a default implementation.

Comment: @MaxPevsner there is an issue on doing this, I've already tired it and I got the result of [this issue](https://gist.github.com/josephlord/5089019943b3667e5516).

Comment: @AhmadF, you're issue is not related to the proposed solution.

Comment: @IlyaLapan, why do you need inheritance? Inheritance does not provide you the _default implementation_ option. Besides, you can have issues like mentioned above.

Comment: @MaxPevsner I want inheritance so that I have a choice between the default protocol and my custom protocol. I edited my answer and added a solution based on what you suggested that should work, but is a little bit messy.

Comment: @MaxPevsner there is still an issue that I don't understand how would I call reloadData() in a default implementation.

Comment: @MaxPevsner I just copied and paste your cod snippets, I got this: "non @ objc does not satisfy optional requirements"

Comment: @IlyaLapan I don't see my proposed solution in your edit. You need to create a separate file, paste my code in it, implement your functionality and it will work like magic. The `reloadData()` should not be called from within the protocol implementation.

Comment: @AhmadF I'm sorry to hear that, but you must have done something wrong. It's a perfectly working solution.

Comment: @MaxPevsner yeah, but if I can't call reload data from delegate, what is the point of the solution? I will just have to reimplement the method again for each table view to call tableView.reloadData(). I still have to repeat the same lines of code for each tableView, but the whole point was to follow DRY

Comment: @IlyaLapan, you can do it technically - you have the reference to the relevant tableView in the function. You shouldn't do it conceptually, but that's beyond the scope of the current question.

Comment: @MaxPevsner The point of the question is how to make a tableView with some default behavior to avoid repetition. Take a look the last edit I made to the post, you might get a better idea of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @IlyaLapan you don't actually need a tableView with default behaviour, you need a screen with default behaviour that contains tableView. TableView just presents data, it should not fetch it. See the edit I've made to my answer.

Comment: @MaxPevsner I already have my model implement all the standard data downloading methods. The point was to create a default behavior for a View (default behavior for the user interface, not for the model). I think you are misunderstanding the main point and focus of my question. The focus is not downloadData() method, it is detecting if the last cell was shown without code repetition. Basically, I don't see any nice way to do it. The solution I presented in my EDIT will work but looks nasty so it is not worth it.

Comment: @IlyaLapan _detecting if the last cell was shown without code repetition_ is exactly what's written in my last edit. `needToLoadMoreData` is a dummy variable - instead of it you should implement your logic. **Once**. _**Only once**_.

Comment: @MaxPevsner, sorry, didn't realise how your idea would work straight away. Now I see it. I'll try that. Thank you!